# How to make 2 drop down menus dependent on another without using values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

Currently, I am trying to set up 3 drop down menus, where the 2nd and 3rd should filter results based on the first one. I searched for this answer, but I was unable to find anything that worked. Here is the code I am working with:

```
       <div class="form-group">
                <label>Item</label><br>
                <select name="item" id="item">
                    <option name="0">Choose an Item</option>
                    <option name="1">Item 1</option>
                    <option name="2">Item 2</option>
                    <option name="3">Item 3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Description</label><br>
            <select name="description" id="description">
                <option name="0"></option>
                <option name="1">Desc 1</option>
                <option name="2">Desc 2</option>
                <option name="3">Desc 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Code</label><br>
            <select name="code" id="code">
                <option name="0"></option>
                <option name="1">Code 1</option>
                <option name="2">Code 2</option>
                <option name="3">Code 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>


$("#item").change(function () {
    if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
        $(this).data('options', $('#description option').clone());
    }
    var id = $(this).find('option:selected').attr("name");
    var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[name=' + id + ']');
    $('#description').html(options);
});


$("#item").change(function () {
    if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
        $(this).data('options', $('#code option').clone());
    }
    var id = $(this).find('option:selected').attr("name");
    var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[name=' + id + ']');
    $('#code').html(options);
});
```

Item is the name of the initial selection I am making, while I would like to filter the description and code options after. Ideally the name of the item selected would filter the other boxes to only show the options associated with that item. Currently, the code shows up as expected, but the description does not. What can I do to change this?

I am attempting to use the names of the options as the key for the filtration as opposed to the values because I do not want to get the values when I get what has been selected in Django. Alternatively, if there is a way to not get the value, but the text instead please tell me I'm being stupid and let me know.

Comment: Can you please upload a fiddle, codepen or plunker?

Comment: @EfeOmoregieElijah https://jsfiddle.net/mybkhw69/1/ On here its not even doing anything though so not sure if I did that right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok let me understand right. You want to allow only items that match options from previous option not copying selected answer from previous option. Look at the fiddle now then tell me if it is close to what you want [jsfiddle.net/mybkhw69/5](http://jsfiddle.net/mybkhw69/5)

Update: [jsfiddle.net/mybkhw69/11](http://jsfiddle.net/mybkhw69/11)

```
$("#item").change(function() {
  var id = $(this).find('option:selected').attr("name");
  $('#description').children('option').filter('[name!=' + id + ']').css('display', 'none').prop("selected", false);
  $('#description').children('option').filter('[name=' + id + ']').css('display', 'block').first().prop("selected", true);
  $('#code').children('option').filter('[name!=' + id + ']').css('display', 'none').prop("selected", false);
  $('#code').children('option').filter('[name=' + id + ']').css('display', 'block').first().prop("selected", true);
});

$("#description").change(function() {
  var id = $(this).find('option:selected').attr("name");
  $('#code').children('option').filter('[name!=' + id + ']').css('display', 'none').prop("selected", false);
  $('#code').children('option').filter('[name=' + id + ']').css('display', 'block').first().prop("selected", true);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I want only options with the same "name" attribute as selected in item to appear. So for example, if Item 1 is selected, that has name="1". Then Desc 1 and Code 1 should be the only options available in the other boxes

Comment: Thank you so much man, this is so close to what I'm looking for, but do you know how update the other selections so that it automatically populates them with a selection? Currently, someone could select everything, then go back and change the item while the other options dont get changed

Comment: Updated. Let me know if it fits your need